# File cannot be found to delete, but has been verified to exists

Tags: vb.net, file-io, console-application, command-prompt

Can anyone think as to why this would be give the error that the file cannot be found? This file definitely exists and when I delete it on the command prompt directly it works fine:

```
Sub Main()
        If System.IO.File.Exists("c:\stuff\a.tif") Then
            Dim info As String = "del \f \q c:\stuff\a.tif"
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Typo - the slashes in your `del` command are wrong. It's trying to delete a file named `f` in the root of whatever drive your current working directory is on. Use the proper forward slashes for options (`/`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your slashes are the wrong types.

Use `del /f /q c:\stuff\a.tif` instead.

Comment: You are right about the forward slashes being the problem i think, but your method does not work either, is there another way to express forward slashes?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/c del /f /q c:\stuff\a.tif") this works thanks for you help

Comment: Probably a bit late now, but why not just use `System.IO.File.Delete("c:\stuff\a.tif")` ??!!

Comment: I was trying to get around the fact that "file was being used by another process" but alas this problem continues

Comment: There's a trick to that.  I can't find it ATM and I'm just leaving work, but if you're showing an image with your code, don't load the image directly from the file - it will get locked.  You can get round it by creating a memory stream (IIRC) and creating the image from that.  Then the 'memory' version can be displayed and the file remains unlocked.

Comment: Wow, you've hit the nail on the head that exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll try to figure out how to do what what you suggested.

Comment: Found it... quite simple stuff really.
    `Using vStream As New FileStream("c:\a.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        Dim vBitmap = CType(Image.FromStream(vStream), Bitmap)
        PictureBox1.Image = vBitmap
    End Using`
I'm fairly certain I got it off a SO question, but I can't find it!

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then System.IO.File.Delete(filename)
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, then it is outside the scope of programming. Check if another application has your file open.